# need the output the below shell script in python code

Tags: python, shell

`echo -e "Size\tFiles\tDirectory"; 
paste <(du -sh ./*/ | sort -k2 | cut -f1) <(find ./*/ | cut -d/ -f2 | uniq -c | sort -k2 | awk '{print ($1-1)"\t"$2}') | sort -nk2`

1. I need output of the above shell script in python code.
2. Is there a way to get the  same output through python code or insert the above script in python code.
3. Also I need to insert the variable in place of  path ./*/ i.e my path is  in the variale e.g x=/usr/bin.

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

use can use library like subprocess ,easyprocess etc from pthon 
which can run commands in pythons and gives output as stdout